# Make a query with Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-views, django-orm

I have used this code to make a query:

**views.py:**

```
        reservations_table = Reservation.objects.all()

        total_commission = 0

        for reservation in reservations_table:
            for city in COMMISSION_RATES.keys():
                if reservation.city == city.upper():
                    total_commission += reservation.net_income * COMMISSION_RATES[city] / 100

        for reservation in reservations_table:
            for month in COMMISSION_PER_MONTH:
                if reservation.checkout.month == month:
                    reservation.monthly = COMMISSION_PER_MONTH[month]

        for reservation in reservations_table_city:
            commission_amount_city += reservation.net_income * COMMISSION_RATES[form.cleaned_data['city']] / 100
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models


class Reservation(models.Model):
    reservation_code = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True)
    checkin = models.DateField()
    checkout = models.DateField()
    flat = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    net_income = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reservation_code
```

**constants.py:**

```
COMMISSION_RATES = {
    'LONDON': 10,
    'PARIS': 12,
    'PORTO': 9,
}
```

How to make a query but using only Django ORM? So, there are 3 queries that work, but the idea is to make them all Django ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. **Be careful**, my code may contain errors, this is only way to solve your problem.

```
reservations_table = Reservation.objects.filter(
    city__in=COMMISSION_RATES.keys(),
).annotate(
    instance_commission=F('net_income') * COMMISSION_RATES[F('city')] / Value(100),
).aggregate(
    total_commission=Sum('instance_commission')
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is on the right track. Now it returns `KeyError: F(city)`. Not able to find the key. Is there a solution for that? The problem seems to be `COMMISSION_RATES[F('city')]`.